# Monstrous task from the Exam : How to copy the sum of two arrays that are inside "IF" statement" that is inside "for nested" loop " to a new array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

I need help with the following Problem:

Create the program that calculates and prints all possible pairs of the following equation (You can use Math.sqrt(double) in your solution but not Math.square )

**n>=a>1**

**n>=b>1**

**Where (a^2 + b^2 = c^2)**

For example if n = 4 , then I'm printing :

System.out.println(a = 3 , b =4 or a = 4 and b =3  ; 3^2 + 4^2=25; we found 1 pair)
  because:
4>=4>1

4>=3>1

4^2 +3^2 =25

16+9=25 ,so this is one pair of a and b (**a= 3** and **b= 4** and **a= 4** and b= **3**  is the same ,so it only gives me one pair )

Another example is: **n =144 , then 144>=144>1 and 144>=17>1**

**144^2 + 17^2 = 21025** , so we found first pair /.

**n = 144 , then 144 >=143>1 and 144 >=24>1**

**143^2 + 24^2 = 21025** ,we found the second pair /.

(n= 144 is giving all previous pairs of numbers , not only those that i'm mentioned)

So I started from Method main  and accompished a few things but recently can't copy the sum of the two arrays:
(cel1 and cel2_copy , their sum is equals to  ) to another array(tempofsum1) properly.

```
   public static void main(String[] args)

 {

  Scanner inp = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.println(" Input the value of n  ");
  int n = inp.nextInt();
  int counter  = 0 ;
  //counts the possible number of digits that gonna insert into my original array

 int counter2 = 0; 
//counts the number of times that our sum is calculated

    int i , j,newroot; // newroot of 25 = 5 , root of 25 = 5.0
    int sumofsquare  = 0; //(a^2 + b^2)
      int  defaultsum  =0; // (a+b)
    int [] tempofsum2,tempofsum1 ;


    for (i = 2; i<=n;i++) 
    {
//counts number of digits that i'm gonna insert into my original array


     counter ++;            
}
     System.out.println("We have to sort out " + counter + " numbers inside our original array \n" ); 


      int [] cel1 = new int [counter] ;// Our Original Array:
//all numbers in our array are equal to zero at the moment

    for ( j = 0 ,  i =2  ; j<cel1.length  ;j++ ,i++ )
      {

//loop that insersts the numbers that I calculated      
// i = 2 is first number in our array ,becasue numbers in the range of  n > 1 

    cel1[j] = i ;

//number at the index of 0 is now 2 , this row is sorting our array numbers in the ascending order

    System.out.println("Value of the original array at the index of # " +j+ " is "  +cel1[j]);
}
    System.out.println("   Our  N is  " + n );


// I'm creating my second array,

      int [ ] cel2_copy = new int [cel1.length];

      for (i = 0;i< cel1.length;i++) 
     { 

//copying values from Original Array to this new .  

        cel2_copy [i] = cel1 [i] ;      
}     

//Our For "Loop", that calculates all possible summary of cel2_copy  and cel1 arrays  , pythagoras triplets, their roots 

    for (i = 0 ; i<cel1.length ;i++) 
      { 
      for ( j = 0 ; j < cel1.length; j++  )
```

//**cel1[i] = a**  and **cel2_copy[j] = b** (in our Pythagoras equation)

```
sumofsquare = cel1[i]*cel1[i] + cel2_copy[j]*cel2_copy[j];

//summing our a^2 +  b^2

    defaultsum = cel1[i] + cel2_copy[j];

//same as previous row but a + b , not a^2 + b^2

    double root = Math.sqrt (sumofsquare);

//calcutates the root of a^2 + b^2

    newroot = (int ) root;

/*
cel1[i] = a , cel2_copy[j]=b
Our If statemenet that gonna check if ( n >= a >1  && n>= b > 1  )and if (our 
integer root of a^2 +b^2  equals to its double value)if it is ,that means 
that we have sum that can be rooted properly.
*/

      if ((((n > cel1[i] || n == cel1[i]) && ( ( cel1[i] >1 ) 
            &&  (n > cel2_copy[j] || n == cel2_copy[j]) 
            && ( (cel2_copy[j] >1 )))
            &&( newroot * newroot == root * root ))))
               {
```

This is my Originofsum array that gets the summary of "cel1" array and "cel2_copy" array

```
        originofsum [i]  = sumofsquare ;

     counter2 ++;

    //counter2 calculates the number of times that we get summary` 

    System.out.println("The sum is calulated " +counter2  + " times "  );
    System.out.println(sumofsquare  + " is sumofsquare " + " at the index of i = "  +i  +" and the index of J = " +j ); 
    System.out.println("Our sum of a = " +cel1[i]+ " and b = " + cel2_copy[j] + " is a+b =" +defaultsum);
    System.out.println("The double root of sumofsquare =" +root );
    System.out.println("The int root of sumofsquare = " +newroot  );
    System.out.println("\n");
     }// end of If                 
   }//end for J
 }// end for I
```

So here I'm trying to copy my sum values from array "OriginofSum" to  "tempofsum1" ,but that not works ,

In console(if you press at the start of the program 4(4 is  N )printed following numbers :0 25

We get two  numbers because my only two sums in the range from 2 to 4 ( n = 4 and n >=a>1 and n>=b>1)that giving me proper square root is a= 3  ,b= 4 and a= 4 and b= 3 (16+9=25) and (9+16=25)

So my array missed number 25 one time.

IF you press 14 , you get sum 8 times  :
0
25
25
169
100
0
100
225

So now my array missed number 169 one time and number 225 one time.(at their places is 0 value).

```
System.out.println("Sum is calculted " +counter2 + " times " );
tempofsum2 = new int [counter2];
tempofsum1 = new int [ counter2];
   for ( i = 0 ; i <tempofsum1.length;i++ ) 
       {


       tempofsum1 [i] = originofsum[i];

       System.out.println(originofsum[i]);

    } // end of For i Loop
 }// end of Main    
}// end of Class
```

I"l be happy to get your help , but remeber that it was a test question ,so I should stick to a basis.
Thank you in advance.)

Comment: So... a and b have to be such that a^2 + b^2 gives a square of a number?

Comment: an integer I'm guessing :)

Comment: I haven't looked too deeply at your code yet, but you set up an inner `for` loop over variable `j` and then never use `j`.

Comment: @IanMcLaird   ,  just changed it , same result .

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder Yes  ,sir , you are right. Thats Pythagoras Theorem  equation.

Comment: So... Why does Fun(144) not return at least 3? After all, 144>=4>1 and 144>=3>1 and 4^2 + 3^2 = 5^2?

Comment: @subrunner We are talking about pairs of the  same Square number ,because : 144^2 + 17^2 = 21025 and 143^2 + 24^2 = 21025 , and    
 3^2 + 4^2 = 25 ,so this is the only one pair that is existing for the square of 5 .  About the return of the number 3 , thats more complex question ,becasue in this case ,I think , method just needs to print all existing pairs for each square  number.I'm at the moment want to be able to get the number of times  that each pair apperas ,if n  =14.

Comment: So there are additional constraints on 'c' or Fun(n) that you forgot to mention? Because so far the whole Fun(n) doesn't make a lot of sense to me... What about 15^2 + 20^2 = 25^2 and 7^2 + 24^2 = 25^2? Does that mean that Fun(24) = 2 too? What about Fun(25)?

Comment: @subrunner You are right, I'm gonna change the question a little bit then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is simply to find numbers that form Pythagorean triples with another integer, this seems pretty straightforward to me:

```
private static void printPairs(int n) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
      long sum = (i * i) + (j * j);
      double root = Math.sqrt(sum);
      if (root == ((int) root)) {
        System.out.printf("Found pair (%d, %d): %d^2 + %d^2 = %d^2\n",
            i, j, i, j, (int) root);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example output:

> Found pair (3, 4): 3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2
>
> Found pair (4, 3): 4^2 + 3^2 = 5^2

Demo: https://ideone.com/dj1w0M

This doesn't require any arrays or anything really complicated. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you , thats great suggestion .                                                           
 Can you just add the part(becasue I still don't get it ) where the program  prints how many times  different pairs giving me the same root ,for example if n =144 , then for root  145^2 it prints number 4, (100^2+105^2)   (143^2  +24^2)   (87^2  +116^2 )  (144^2 +17^2)               because each of these pairs is 145^2 (but 100^2+105^2   and  105^2+100^2 is the same pair ,so it's  counts li ke one pair)

Comment: @David93: Perhaps that should be a separate question? But it basically boils down to: store the roots you find in a data structure, and check each time to see if you've found a new root. For example, you could use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` where the key is the root and the value is the number of times you've encountered it.